# Django Attribute Error

Tags: python, django, models

I have 2 models and a Foreign Key between them

```
class League(models.Model):
    """
    League Info
    """
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    FUTBOL = 'FUT'
    FUTBOLITO = 'FT7'
    OTRO = 'OTH'

    LEAGUE_CHOICES = (
        (FUTBOL, 'Fútbol'),
        (FUTBOLITO, 'Futbolito'),
        (OTRO, 'Otro'),
    )

    MASCULINO = 'M'
    FEMENINO = 'F'
    MULTIPLE = 'A'
    SEX_CHOICE = (
        (MASCULINO, 'Masculino'),
        (FEMENINO, 'Femenino'),
        (MULTIPLE, 'Femenino y Masculino'),
    )

    league_type = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=3, choices=LEAGUE_CHOICES, default=FUTBOLITO)
    league_sex = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SEX_CHOICE, default=MASCULINO)

    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=200)
```

The second Model is

```
class Division(models.Model):
    """
    Division of a League  e.g. Junior, Senior; First Division, Second Division
    """

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


    MASCULINO = 'M'
    FEMENINO = 'F'
    MULTIPLE = 'A'
    SEX_CHOICE = (
        (MASCULINO, 'Masculino'),
        (FEMENINO, 'Femenino'),
        (MULTIPLE, 'Femenino y Masculino'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=200)  # name required

    league = models.ForeignKey(League, blank=False)
    league_name = league.name
    league_type = league.league_type
    league_sex = league.league_sex
```

when I run syncdb i got an error :  AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'league_type'

I got the same error with league_sex,  but don't get it with league_name, which seems to be ok. The app is on the setiings Installed Apps

Comment: `league_name = league.name` this is not the right way to define model fields. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I just need some info (fields) from the related model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, just remove following lines from `Division` model:

```
league_name = league.name
league_type = league.league_type
league_sex = league.league_sex
```

Later on if you want to access league info from division object you can do:

```
division = Division.objects.get(id=some_id)
league = division.league
print league.name
print league.league_type
```

I think you are just confused.